# jquery Datatables eu-date not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort eu date (dd/mm/yyyy) using data tables but it's not working as expected and not ordering date as it should be,

http://jsfiddle.net/CYubV/55/

[image]

**JS**

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-eu-pre": function (date) {
        date = date.replace(" ", "");

        if (!date || date == "-") {
            return -1;
        }

        var year;
        var eu_date = date.split(/[\.\-\/]/);

        /*year (optional)*/
        if (eu_date[2]) {
            year = eu_date[2];
        } else {
            year = 0;
        }

        /*month*/
        var month = eu_date[1];
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = 0 + month;
        }

        /*day*/
        var day = eu_date[0];
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = 0 + day;
        }

        return (year + month + day) * 1;
    },

        "date-eu-asc": function (a, b) {
        if (a == '-') return 1;
        else if (b == '-') return -1;
        else return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

        "date-eu-desc": function (a, b) {
        if (a == '-') return 1;
        else if (b == '-') return -1;
        else return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});

$('#table').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "footer": false,
        "info": false,
        "aoColumns": [null, {
        type: 'date-eu',
        targets: 0
    }]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id=table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Normal</th>
            <th>date-eu</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>29/10/2011</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>03/12/2035</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>20/01/2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-5</td>
            <td>03/12/2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>04/05/2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**I want to display "-" at bottom all the times also.**

Comment: typo mistake in picture there with "2045" instead of "2035" if anyone gets confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, few other answers on SO are incorrect,

**Fixed JS**

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-eu-asc": function (a, b) {
        if (a == '-') return 1;
        else if (b == '-') return -1;
        else {
            var aDay = a.split('/')[0]
            var aMonth = a.split('/')[1]
            var aYear = a.split('/')[2]
            var a = new Date(aMonth + "/" + aDay + "/" + aYear).getTime();

            var bDay = b.split('/')[0]
            var bMonth = b.split('/')[1]
            var bYear = b.split('/')[2]
            var b = new Date(bMonth + "/" + bDay + "/" + bYear).getTime();

            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        }
    },

        "date-eu-desc": function (a, b) {
        if (a == '-') return 1;
        else if (b == '-') return -1;
        else {
            var aDay = a.split('/')[0]
            var aMonth = a.split('/')[1]
            var aYear = a.split('/')[2]
            var a = new Date(aMonth + "/" + aDay + "/" + aYear).getTime();

            var bDay = b.split('/')[0]
            var bMonth = b.split('/')[1]
            var bYear = b.split('/')[2]
            var b = new Date(bMonth + "/" + bDay + "/" + bYear).getTime();

            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    }
});

$('#table').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [null, {
        type: 'date-eu',
        targets: 0
    }]
});
```

Make sure to add reference to latest version of dataTables to make it work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/CYubV/65/